# A program to read a file and print out the sum of the numbers in the file. The file contains a single floating point numbers separated by commas

Tags: python, file, text

For example, if your file contained:

```
-2.5, 2.0
8.0
100.0, 3.0, 5.1, 3.6
6.5
```

Then a sample run of your program would look like:

```
Please enter your file name:  nums.txt
The sum of your numbers is 125.7.
```

I have run the program but it is giving me an error, saying that 
"sum_number = sum_number + float(i)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'"

Any help will be appreciated!

```
filename = input("Please enter your file name: ")
sum_number = 0
openthefile = open(filename, "r")

for i in openthefile:
    Split = i.split(',')
    Join = "".join(Split)
    print(Join)

for i in Join:
    sum_number = sum_number + float(i)

print("The sum of your numbers is",sum_number)
```

Comment: So even though you say "single" floating point [number], you can have multiple lines, and each line can have multiple numbers?

Comment: cannot you print i in the latter for loop and see  if it has a valid number on each iteration?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
filename = input("Please enter your file name: ")
sum_number = 0
openthefile = open(filename, "r")

for line in openthefile:
    for num in line.split(','):
        sum_number = sum_number + float(num.strip())

print("The sum of your numbers is %.1f" %(sum_number))
```

We simply cycle through each line of the file, split all the values on the line by the `,`, and add each value on each line to our total sum. At the end, we print out the value.

Comment: printing out: The sum of your numbers is 6.5

Comment: it should appear: sum_number += sum_number + float(num.strip())

Comment: Is it working for you now? `+=` adds the value on the right to the value on the left, so you shouldn't need to have `sum_number` on the right as well. It prints out 125.7 on my computer when I run it.

Comment: if i copy and paste your code in python, i just get "The sum of your numbers is 6.5" as an output

Comment: `filename = input("Please enter your file name: ")`
    `openthefile = open(filename, "r")`
    `sum_number = 0

    for line in openthefile:
        for numbers in line.split(","):
            sum_number = sum_number + float(numbers.strip())

    print("The sum of your numbers is", sum_number)`

Comment: Its curious though why it didn't work with the `+=` regardless, but glad everything is working well!

Answer (score 1):

You can use map and sum with a generator expression:

```
filename = input("Please enter your file name: ")

with open(filename) as f: # closes your file automatically
    print("The sum of your numbers is {:.1f}".format(sum(sum(map(float, line.split(","))) for line in f)))

The sum of your numbers is 125.7
```

You are trying to join all the floats and then cast i.e:

```
float("100.03.05.13.6")
```

So with `for i in Join:` you are iterating over each character of the joined string  which gives the error you see as `.` cannot be cast to a float.

`{:.1f}` formats to 1 decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = input("Please enter your file name: ")

lst = []
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lst.extend(line.split(','))

lst = map(float, lst)

print(sum(lst))  # 125.7
```

This creates an empty list, then for each line, adds the elements obtained from splitting that line over the comma to the list.  The last two steps converts the elements to floats and prints the sum.

Or, instead of keeping track of all the elements in a list, keep track of *only* the sum:

```
filename = input("Please enter your file name: ")

total = 0
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for elem in line.split(','):
            total += float(elem)

print(total)  # 125.7
```

Comment: Not sure about the unexplained downvote, but the solution is correct ::shrug::

Answer (score 0):

You can just print the sum of all the values by using a generator

```
with open(filename,"r")as f:
    print sum(float(e) for line in f for e in line.split(","))

>> 125.7
```

Comment: you don't need to strip to cast to a float

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you are right,  I created the habit of doing it  but it should be removed